# let anchor tag not firing when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery Ajax to grab data. I want to have all anchor tags in my code that if somebody clicks on a tag, it doesn't fire and call Ajax instead. The following is my code, but it does not work.

```
$('.one_item a').each(function(){
    $(this).live('click', function(){
        alert($(this).attr('href'));
        return false;
    });
});
```

I am using JQuery version 1.5, so .live should work. Any ideas? Cheers.

Comment: Are these dynamically added? If so, `.live` has to be applied to the selector, not specific elements.

Comment: Can you show the `HTML` ?

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean? Do you mean that the alerted href is wrong? Or that the anchor hop is not prevented? Or that nothing happens?

Comment: Did you forget the `DOM Ready` handler ?

Answer (score 4):

`.live` has to be applied to the selector. When you use `.each()`, you don't get the benefit of handling events on elements added dynamically, because you're just iterating over the elements found at the time the loop was run.

```
$('.one_item a').live('click', function(){
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Hi, thx for your reply. It still keeps iterating alert $(this).attr('href'). There are like 20 items with the same structure. (<div class="one_item"><a href=""></a></div>)How can I make it fire only on the items I clicked?

Comment: Sorry, Barmar. It works. It iterates because I called the function inside a loop. Shame on me!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.live()` directly on the selector:

```
$('.one_item a').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

It should work, [see this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/XZVKF/).

> However, it keeps iterating `alert($(this).attr('href'));`. How can I make it fire only on the items I clicked?

Make sure you are not triggering the `click()` event loop somewhere else, such as:

```
$('.one_item a').each(function() {
    $(this).click();
    // other stuff
});
```

Comment: `.on` wasn't added until jQuery 1.7, he's using 1.5.

Comment: @Barmar yeah, missed that, fixed.

Comment: Hi, Thx. I managed to get it working using .click. However, it keeps iterating alert $(this).attr('href'). How can I make it fire only on the items I clicked?

Comment: Hi Barmar, I just tried your code. Still having the same issue.